# Manipulate DOMDocument with PHP

Tags: php, html, dom, domdocument, domxpath

1&1 hosting service is leaving Poland, my country with their services, so they told every their client to move out. Because there's no way to export the website, I need to parse it manually and retrieve data I want.

Basically it's about to export all articles with image attachments.

I'm trying to manipulate the HTML from this site: http://www.naszeiganie.org/lata-2014-2015/ to have each post in the individual `div` element, to properly parse the whole document and retrieve mixed data, that articles have.

I figured that every article starts with a:

`<div class="n module-type-header diyfeLiveArea ">
    <h2>
        <span class="diyfeDecoration">`

and there's no repeatable end of the "article". In fact, next instance of above code is telling me, that current post is ending, and the new one begins.

```
function smi_parse_web(){
$url = 'http://www.naszeiganie.org/lata-2014-2015/';
$content     = file_get_contents($url);
$doc         = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($content);
libxml_clear_errors();
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$node   = $finder->query('//div[contains(@class,"module-type-header")]/h2');
foreach($node as $anchor){
    if($anchor->nodeName == 'h2')
        {
            $element = $doc->createElement('div', 'x');
            $element->setAttribute('class','DIV-WRAP');
            $element->insertBefore($anchor);
        }
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

I figured out something like this, but the effect is none. The found `$anchor` clears out it's content.

**My target is** to find all the html content between one and another `div > h2` combination and wrap it up in the `div.wrap`

What would you suggest to do to move on with the project? Maybe I've gone wrong while the simpliest way is on my hand?

Thanks a lot!

(I know how to deal with images, but I want them to be attached to each downloaded article)

Comment: How is it not possible to get your website from the hosting provider? Did you exceed some notification period and now can't access your files? Web scraping your own website feels horribly wrong...

Comment: Have you ever tried 1&1 hosting service? It's totally click-by website generator without any access to files and structure.
PS. It's my client's website, I didn't choose it, now I need to move it.

Comment: Are you trying to recreate the same website with some modifications or do you really only need an actual content (titles, texts, images, etc.)?

Comment: I'm about to move the site on to WordPress, thus I need only some portions of data, exactly: titles(with dates in given format), text, images.

Comment: I'd say first create a post template (HTML for your WP posts), second find a CSV import plugin for WP. Then generate a CSV file according to the format accepted by that particular plugin using your template. You could also generate SQL to insert posts into your WP database.

Comment: I got it covered when it comes to place things in WP(from CSV, XML, or an array - whatever), just need the data in proper format. So, do you suggest, the smartest way is to manual copy things from website to CSV? What about images?

Comment: I'm suggesting to get a proper content for each separate post but in your code snippet you're clearly trying to manipulate an HTML containing multiple posts and then save that modified structure to a file. But resulting HTML will be useless for you - you should import individual posts into WP  and then you can create a page containing list of filtered post just like on a page you linked. All assets will have to be downloaded and somehow "referenced" in your export file to be recreated as URLs in your new template (you have to think about the new location of the files).

Comment: Btw. `if($anchor->nodeName == 'h2')` seems to be redundant - you already have `.../h2` in your XPath. You should also take a look at [http://php.net/manual/pl/domnode.insertbefore.php](http://php.net/manual/pl/domnode.insertbefore.php). You're basically removing `$anchor` from `$doc` and appending it to children of `$element` while not adding `$element` anywhere into a `$doc`.

Comment: If you are willing to help, please let's focus on the part that does structurizes given HTML into a portions of data that will be easy to work with. Let's say I look for a solution to create an array that corresponds the article's parts: title, text, gallery images. Thanks for your good will.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm quite busy now. If nobody helps I'll try to get to this during a weekend. But you should really try to look at the source of the page with browser's built-in dev tools and pull posts data bit by bit with those XPaths...